# Create database on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have to create new database (from database files .mdf, .ldf) on Azure (portal.azure.com) programmatically (when new client request it). 
What is best practice to do this?

Do I have to store database files somewhere on Azure (blob storage maybe?) and create database from them. And how?

Is it good solution to create database using Azure portal, and then, on client demand, copy database using: CREATE DATABASE Database1_copy AS COPY OF database?
I tried this and it works, but I am not sure if it is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would you using [PowerShell cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-create-and-configure-database-powershell) for creating Azure SQL database

Also, I would recommend giving a try for [Azure SQL database Elastic Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool). It has more benefits for managing multiple Azure SQL databases.